# Setting autorevoke for URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I am trying to create a blob in Javascript to serve up a file. However, the link created by `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` becomes invalid over time. I wish to be able to generate a link that will be valid for as long as the page is open. Looking online, I saw that the autoRevoke option is set to true, so this led me to believe that the url is being revoked when not being used actively. I tried setting it to false, but I get a TypeError.

Here is the code:

```
var res = xhr.response;
var blob = new Blob([res]);
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, {autoRevoke : false});
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Type error background.js:52
```

How can I prevent the blob's url from becoming invalid?

Comment: Note: autoRevoke is no longer a thing. This functionality was re-added to the spec as URL.createFor. Though has not been implemented by browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the blob to the file system using the API discussed here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

You can create a file system URL that will persist. This solution does have the downside of a prompt to the user to approve saving files.

Can you talk more about the feature as the user would see it? What are you linking to?

In response to your comment:
I recommend keeping the input element in the DOM for as long as you want to hold a reference to the file's content. If you're linking to the content, you could create create a link that invokes a function with the input element's unique id. This function would generate a blob URL on demand and forward the browser to that URL. If you're using the URL as an img src or something similar, then perhaps your app has a user interaction that still allows for you to create the blob URL on demand.

Comment: I am trying to cache the blob in memory until the user decides they want to save it to the filesystem.